# Creating a view in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error, sqlplus

I am trying to do something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW FOO AS SELECT ...;
/

BEGIN
    SELECT ...;
    INSERT ...;
    UPDATE ...;
    DELETE ...;
END
/

DROP VIEW FOO;
/
```

But this doesn't work:

'ERROR at line 14: ORA-00911: invalid character' at the end of the create view statement.

'ERROR at line 4: ORA-06550: line 4, column 2: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following ...'

What is the correct amount and position of semicolons or slashes to make this work?

Comment: Get rid of the semi-colon at the end of the `CREATE VIEW` and `DROP VIEW` statements - semi=colons are not used when executing SQL statements in SQL*Plus.

Comment: The error ultimately was a '--' comment directly after a semicolon. SQLplus for some obscure reason doesn't allow those.

Comment: Old thread, but the character currently set as [sqlterminator](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG109) will certainly be used to terminate SQL statements in SQL\*Plus. Also, it parses one line at a time, and it expects the SQL terminator to be at the end, excluding whitespace. It doesn't parse the whole line in case the current terminator character is embedded between multiple statements or comments etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE VIEW FOO AS SELECT 1 NUM FROM DUAL;
DECLARE
    i NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 INTO i FROM DUAL;
END;
/

DROP VIEW FOO;
```

Works without any problems for me. Please add your entire `CREATE VIEW` statement.

Comment: When I execute your example, I get:

View created.

CREATE VIEW FOO AS SELECT 1 "num" FROM dual
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object



PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


View dropped.

DROP VIEW FOO
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Maybe I should have added that I execute it in sqlplus: sqlplus user/pass@instance @script.sql

Comment: You probably already have object FOO in your schema and it is procedure or a package. select * from all_objects where object_name = 'FOO' would help.

Comment: I removed the '/' immediately following the 'create view' command.  It's not required, and it's re-executing the 'create view'.  The first 'create view' succeeds, the second execution, view FOO already exists, and you get ORA-00955.  Same with the '/' following the 'drop view'.  I got rid of that one too.  Code should now run error free.

Comment: Lower (and mixed) cased column names are not a great idea. Now you need to always quote that column name and have an exact case match.

Comment: @RobvanWijk Thanks for pointing that out. I usually write in lower case, but decided to follow Zakub's style, and that caused the style mismatch. I edited the post.

Comment: @RobvanWijk: mixed case is not a problem as long as you don't use quoted identifiers.